# SVG textpath misaligned with path in IE11 and incorrect font size in Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, safari, internet-explorer-11

The following bit of SVG code renders fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE11 (though IE11 for some reason renders it in a small box which has been [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922263/internet-explorer-not-honoring-svg-percentage-width)):

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="MyPath" d="
    M 100,200
    A 150,200 0 0,1 450,500"/>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"  />

  <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="42.5">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      The wheels of the bus go round and round
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

However, when setting the viewbox to `viewBox="0 0 1 1"` and scaling down all the SVG values accordingly, it displays fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera (other than an ever-so-slight change in font size) but IE11 displays weird misaligned text and Safari doesn't seem to honour the font-size property and displays gigantic text:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 5 5"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="MyPath2" d="
    M 1,2
    A 1.5,2 0 0,1 4.5,5"/>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#MyPath2" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.01"  />

  <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="0.425">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath2">
      The wheels of the bus go round and round
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Note that the IDs for the paths are different in the two code blocks. I don't know why and I couldn't find anything about it, but IE11 apparently requires each path to have a unique ID even if the two paths are in separate  elements.

This seems to occur in IE11 only when using the A(rc) operator. Using a bezier C(urve) works fine. I haven't tested other path operators, though.

Is this is a bug in IE11/Safari or does SVG simply not support floating-point numbers in these cases?

Either way I can simply make sure I only use ints for these things in my SVGs but I'd like to make sure nothing else is going on.

EDIT: I've tracked the Safari font-size issue to [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20192) which was considered resolved but is clearly reproducible again. I have requested it to be reopened.

Comment: The SVG specification allows floating point numbers in this case.

Comment: Note: `document.getElementByID()` returns a single element, hence all ID's needs to be unique on same page, if there is a conflict, it returns the first ID found.

Comment: D'oh! My bad. For a second I thought Chrome and Firefox were only looking for IDs defined within the same <svg> element. This is, of course, not the case.