# How should I ensure SVG's scale properly across all browsers when given 100% width and no height?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser

I have discovered an SVG scaling situation that IE 10 and IE 11 handle different than most other browsers, and I'm wondering if this is an area where IE's behavior is "wrong" and I need to write code specifically to handle this bug, or if I'm misunderstanding SVGs and I should be doing something different entirely.

The situation is when you have an svg with width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" and height undefined inside of parent container with an explicit width, and no explicit height. In chrome and other browsers, the browser scales the SVG to take up the fill width of the parent, and then scales the height of the svg up according to the aspect ratio defined by the viewbox. An example is defined in the following snippet.

```js
var document = window.document
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.setAttribute("style", "width:200px;")
var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 100 100")
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "100%")

var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 0);
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100');
svg.appendChild(rect);
div.appendChild(svg)
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

In this particular example the parent container is explicitly set at 200px and the svg scales up to be 200x200, with the rect inside the SVG filling that entire space.

In IE, for some reason the browser doesn't properly scale the height of the SVG element. The developer tools say that the SVG is 200x150. The rect inside the SVG is only scaled up to be 150x150, so the aspect ratio is preserved, but it's not clear why the overall size is smaller.

Is there a good cross browser way to ensure the SVG scales up appropriately in the situation where I don't want to set an explicit height? Or should I take my snippet above, and use it to detect when I'm dealing with a buggy SVG implementation and write specific code for those scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer Not Honoring SVG Percentage Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922263/internet-explorer-not-honoring-svg-percentage-width)

Comment: Ps : a quick fix is to ensure that one of the parent containers has a defined `height`.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the whole point of this is I don't want a defined height. I want the svg to take up the width of the parent completely, and scale it's height accordingly. In my actual application, setting a defined height creates issues with responsiveness.